# Adding a private network - basic question

Tags: routing

This may seem obvious but after searching can't find an answer. I have built many smaller networks using static IP addresses where the default gateway is the router going to the internet.

I would like to add a private network that has no internet access and add things like backup NAS. In a simple scenario, say two servers and a workstation add a new switch, connect the NAS and the second NIC in the servers/workstation and just assign a unique (for our network) class C 192.168.0.0/16 (255.255.0.0) IP address/subnet.

The bit that confuses me is what to do about the default gateway, as no gateway as such is required. Do we need a router even though that network is only internal? If not how do I set this parameter?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration you want is fine, there will be no default gateway on that subnet, so for instance on a Windows host or Linux GUI that field would be left blank in the network setup.

Answer (score -1):

Create a saparate Vlan  in router , if your are using router configure one sub-interface or if using layer3 then Configure SVi and allow traffic thought all downstream switches through trunkport . Exclude this Vlan subnet from NAT overload policy Configured in edge device . So that this Vlan subnet cannot access internet access .

Now this Vlan is totally isolated in setup can be used for back NAS purposes or for other purpose as well.

Comment: The OP stated there's *no Internet access* and *no router*.

Comment: Team requires router to accomplish this requirement . And internet access is not provided for this newly created vlan